# Access FTP from outside the LAN

Tags: networking, ftp, firewall, centos6.5

I've a Centos Server. If login via the private IP while in the LAN, I can connect to FTP. If I try to login when outside the LAN, I receive a timeout error.

iptables is not configured, so it shouldn't be the problem. `iptables -L -n returns` an empty list.

I'm using vsftpd

The server is in a hosting I don't have control on. At the moment I can't ask to the sysadmin of the hosting if there's something blocking port 21.

What could I check on my server? Is there any way I can determine for sure if the port is blocked from a firewall outside my server?

Thanks.

Comment: Are you using private or public IP when outside the LAN? What client are you using? Do you get the timeout straight away when connecting, or only when the client tries to retrieve directory listing?

Answer (score 1):

Go to http://www.yougetsignal.com/tools/open-ports/ and test your public IP on port 20 and 21. If it says **closed** then something is blocking the communication to that port. It could be neccesary to do one, some or all the following tasks:

- to configure a firewall
- to open the port in a router
- to route the port in the router to your server

Comment: Port is blocked. There's no firewall set, so it shouldn't be the problem right?

Comment: The public IP is used by more than one server? In that case you will need to open and route ports in the router.

Comment: The public IP is dedicated to this server.

Comment: You will ned to ask the sysadmin about this, because there should be a router in the middle that is dropping all that go to ports 20 and 21.

Answer (score 0):

Private IPs are not reachable via the internet. Try to use DnyDNS to get a round this problem or get an official IP for your internet access and configure your firewall/router with NAT to access your internal devices.

Comment: The server has a public IP also and is linked to a domain name.